# f(n) = log(n)^m is O(n) for all natural numbers m?

Tags: big-o

A TA told me that this is true today but I was unable to verify this by googling. This is saying functions like log(n)^2, log(n)^3, ... , log(n)^m are all O(n).

Is this true?

Comment: It appears to be true, though it's not immediately obvious to me how to prove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Claim***

> The function `f(n) = log(n)^m`, for any natural number `m > 2` (`m ∈ ℕ+`) is in
>   `O(n)`.
>
> I.e. there exists a set of positive constants `c` and `n0` such that
>   the following holds:
>
> ```
> log(n)^m < c · n, for all n > n0, { m > 2 | m ∈ ℕ+ }      (+)
> ```

---

***Proof***

- Assume that `(+)` does **not** hold, and denote this assumption as `(*)`.

I.e., given `(*)`, there exists no set of positive constants `c` and `n0` such that `(+)` holds for any value of `m > 2`. Under this assumption, the following holds, that *for all positive constants `c` and `n0`, there exists a `n > n0` such that* (thanks @Oriol):

```
 log(n)^m ≥ c · n, { m > 2 | m ∈ ℕ+ }                       (++)
```

Now, if `(++)` holds, then the inequality in `(++)` will hold also after applying any monotonically increasing function to both sides of the inequality. One such function is, conveniently, the `log` function itself

[image]

Hence, under the assumption that `(++)` holds, then, *for all positive constants `c` and `n0`, there exists a `n > n0` such that the following holds*

```
 log(log(n)^m) ≥ log(c · n), { m > 2 | m ∈ ℕ+ }

 m · log(log(n)) ≥ log(c · n), { m > 2 | m ∈ ℕ+ }           (+++)
```

However, `(+++)` is obviously a contradiction: since `log(n)` dominates (w.r.t. growth) over `log(log(n))`,

[image]

we can—for any given value of `m > 2`—always find a set of constants `c` and `n0` such that `(+++)` (and hence `(++)`) is violated for all `n > n0`.

Hence, assumption `(*)` is proven false by contradiction, and hence, `(+)` holds.

> => for `f(n) = log(n)^m`, for any finite integer `m > 2`, it holds that `f ∈ O(n)`.

Comment: I think the negation of (+) is `for all positive constants c and n0, there exists a n>n0, such that log(n)^m ≥ c · n`. Your answer says `for all n > n0`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. If the function it's `f(n)`, it means `m` is a parameter and `f` does not depend on it. In fact, we have a different `f_m` function for each `m`.

```
f_m(n) = log(n)^m
```

Then it's easy. Given `m ∈ ℕ`, use [L'Hôpital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) repeatively

```
        f_m(n)            log(n)^m            m * log(n)^(m-1)
limsup ──────── = limsup ────────── = limsup ────────────────── =
 n→∞      n        n→∞       n         n→∞           n

          m*(m-1) * log(n)^(m-2)                m!
= limsup ──────────────────────── = … = limsup ──── = 0
                 n                       n→∞    n
```

Therefore, `f_m ∈ O(n)`.

Of course, it would be different if we had `f(m,n) = log(n)^m`. For example, taking `m=n`,

```
        f(n,n)            log(n)^n
limsup ──────── = limsup ────────── = ∞
 n→∞      n        n→∞       n
```

Then `f ∉ O(n)`

Answer (score 0):

In many ways it is more intuitive that for any positive integer `m` we have:

```
x^m = O(e^x)
```

This says that exponential growth dominates polynomial growth (which is why exponential time algorithms are bad news in computer programming).

Assuming that this is true, simply take `x = log(n)` and use the fact that then `x` tends to infinity if and only if `n` tends to infinity and that `e^x` and `log(x)` are inverses:

```
log(n)^m = O(e^log(n)) = O(n)
```

Finally, since for any natural number `m`, the root function `n => n^(1/m)` is increasing, we can rewrite the result as

```
log(n) = O(n^(1/m))
```

This way of writing it says that `log(n)` grows slower than any root (square, cube, etc.) of `n`, which more obviously corresponds to `e^n` growing faster than any power of `n`.

---

On Edit: the above showed that `log(n)^m = O(n)` followed from  the more familiar `x^m = O(e^x)`. To convert it to a more self-contained proof, we can show the later somewhat directly.

Start with the Taylor series for `e^x`:

```
e^x = 1 + x/1! + x^2/2! + x^3/3! + ... + x^n/n! + ...
```

This is known to converge for all real numbers `x`. If a positive integer `m` is given, let `K = (m+1)!`. Then, if `x > K` we have `1/x < 1/(m+1)!`, hence

```
x^m = x^(m+1)/x < x^(m+1)/(m+1)! < e^x
```

which implies `x^m = O(e^x)`. (The last inequality in the above is true since all terms in the expansion for `e^x` are strictly positive if `x>0` and `x^(m+1)/(m+1)!` is just one of those terms.)